# Difference between a View and Saved Query

Tags: sql-server, view, ssms

Ignoring an Indexed View, is the following a correct understanding of a View as it is done in SQL Server?

1. It is almost like a "Saved Query" that can be shared with other users like any other database objects.
2. It cannot have an index (since nothing is stored -- it's just a saved query).

In other words, is a view a fancy way of saying a "Saved Query", such as:

[image]

Or are there parts about the `view` that I'm missing?

Comment: Thats pretty much it. Its a reusable piece of SQL. Any final query plan takes into account the entire query including the view SQL.

Comment: @DaleK does a user with access to the view able to see the query as well?

Comment: I'm not sure. That is however another good use of a view, you can grant read permissions to the view even if the user doesn't have read permissions on the base table(s).

Comment: I assume you've read the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-ver15)?